# Dynamic search in one to many core data relationship in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, relationship, predicate

I have 2 entities in my CoreData model.Book and Quotes. Book has one to many relationship with Quotes. I'm displaying all the quotes with related book in a sectioned list. Section headers show the book titles and related quotes are shown in QuoteView(). I want to add a dynamic search to find a specific quote. But I could only display all the quotes related to a book. This is because I'm filtering the book that contains the quote, not the quote itself. What I want to achieve is to display only the specific quote. I could fetch all the quotes and filter them, but in this case I cannot show the related books. I could not figure out how to filter a specific attribute in a one to many relationship with predicates. Hope I could explain.
Here is my code:

```
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Book.title, ascending: true)])

    private var books: FetchedResults<Book>

    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var searchQuery: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
           searchText
           } set: { newValue in
           searchText = newValue
    
           guard !newValue.isEmpty else {
              books.nsPredicate = nil
              return
           }
          books.nsPredicate = NSPredicate( format: "quotes.quote contains[cd] %@", newValue)
         }
     }
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            ForEach(books, id: \.self){ book in
                if book.quotes?.count != 0 {
                    Section(header:Text(book.title ?? "")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("OrangeColor"))
                                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 18))){
                        ForEach(Array((book.quotes as? Set<Quote> ?? []).sorted(by: { $0.quote! < $1.quote! })), id:\.self){ quote in
                            NavigationLink{
                                DetailQuoteView(quote: quote, selectedBook: book)
                            } label: {
                                QuoteView(quote: quote) }
                        }
                        .onDelete{
                            self.delete(at: $0, in: book)}
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: searchQuery)
        //code...
     }
   }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you want to display your quotes sectioned by books, then you need to make your 'fetchRequest()' on the quotes and section them by book, not the other way around. If you then want to search in that list for a particular word or full quote, then you would filter the quotes, not do a different 'fetchRequest()'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could achieve it with @SectionedFetchRequest.